# Selecting Options one by one Using watir-webdriver-

Tags: ruby, watir

```
b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpVehicleType").when_present.options.each do |option|
    option.select

    b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").when_present.options.each do |option|
        option.select

        b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpModel").when_present.options.each do |option|
            option.select

            b.button(:id,"MainContent_imgbtnsearch").click
        end
    end
end
```

I'm Having Three Dropdown Each Dropdown Depends on the Previous Values I have to select each option one by one and  then click Button . ******While Doing like that getting following Error****  Element is no longer attached to the DOM (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::StaleElementReferenceError)**

**Also Tried:**

```
 b.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3
```

Comment: The problem is likely that watir is trying to access options before the dropdowns have refreshed. You need a way to determine when the dropdown has finished refreshing - likely checking that the values of the dropdown have changed (noting that this would only work if each set of options is unique).

Comment: Thanks for reply..But i'm having more than 100 options value it is impossible to set each value..is there any method is available to determine to wait till options refresh...

Comment: Is the list of "makes" unique for each "vehicle type"? Similarly, is the list of "models" unique for each "make"?

Comment: Yes values all are unique ..

Comment: you can use sleep for 5 seconds of after you selected a value. did you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following,

```
b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpVehicleType").when_present.options.each do |type_option|
  type_option.select
  sleep 5
  b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").when_present.options.each do |make_option|
    make_option.select
    sleep 5
    b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpModel").when_present.options.each do |model_option|
      model_option.select
      sleep 5
      b.button(:id,"MainContent_imgbtnsearch").click
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: While this might work, it could be quite slow given that 100+ options are being tested.

Comment: Thanks for Reply..Still Occurs Same Error

Comment: wow.. the BUTTON is giving no longer attached to the dom when you try to click it.   I could understand for the select lists etc, but the button? really? even with the sleep in front of it as above?  wow.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that each option is unique, you could try:

1. Get the last option in the dependent list
2. Make a selection in your current list
3. Wait for the option in Step 1 to no longer appear

The following implements this idea (though it has not been tested since I do not have a similar page to test against):

```
b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpVehicleType").when_present.options.each do |option|

    #Select a vehicle type and wait for the last make option to no longer appear
    last_make_option = b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").when_present.options.last
    option.select
    last_make_option.wait_while_present

    b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpMake").when_present.options.each do |option|

        #Select a make and wait for the last model option to no longer appear
        last_model_option = b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpModel").when_present.options.last
        option.select
        last_model_option.wait_while_present

        b.select_list(:id, "MainContent_drpModel").when_present.options.each do |option|
            option.select

            b.button(:id,"MainContent_imgbtnsearch").click
        end
    end
end
```

Note that:

- The code assumes that the last option of the dependent list will always change. If this is not true, you might need to check against all options of the dependent list.

Comment: Thanks for Reply ...getting same error..Let me Explain my Problem Clearly

1) In Vechile Type having three options AUTO,HD,MARINE

2) If i Have Selected the Vechile Type Auto Means Related to tat Vechile Make need to be loaded in Make Dropdown 

3) After tat Selecting Model Option ,(It contains only one value for all makes).

4)After Tat Clicking Searching  Button 

5)Now it will Display All Values Related to search

6)Like that i have to check for each and every options and clicking the search button and need to display All Values Related to search

Comment: If you hard-code one specific example (ie rather than looping through all options), are there any errors? If not, then I would guess that Chuck is right in there being something refreshing. Access to the page or html that reproduces the problem would really help.

Comment: yes chuck is correct ...after clicking button it is refreshing ..and sorry not able to provide access to tat page..

Answer (score 0):

One concern I have is what happens after the click?  if the page refreshes or does something such that then you could very well be toast with the nested approach above since after that first click, there's no way to change your choice on the third list and click again..

If none of the above work, you might have to do a little snooping to see what sort of HTML requests (probably to a REST API) are taking place when you make a choice on the list. You might be able to Use that to build your own sort of multi-dimensional array to map the choices.  Or you might be able to get the various select list contents with a loop structure similar to what you have above, THEN loop through and do your clicks

Once you have the map, iterate over it dimension by dimension using nested loops similar to above but doing all your actions in the innermost loop, something that amounts to this psuedo-code

```
gather the types and store
for each stored-type do
  pick the type 
  gather makes available for that type and store
  for each make of that type do
    pick the type, then make
    gather models available for that type
    for each model of that make do
      goto starting point
      select type
      select make
      select model
      click
      validate what should happen
    end
   end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your valuable time..The page does not refreshing ..and am not validating anything else..Just i need to  display the Information Related to  particular dropdown (Vechile type,Make,Model)..Any Idea

Comment: Once it refreshes, all those object collections pretty much get invalidated.  rather than work with dynamic collections, you are likely going to have to get contents of lists, extract to your own collections (multi-dimensional array perhaps) and then use the stored values inside loops that make the selections

Comment: I enhanced the psuedocode a bit more to make it clearer (I hope) the approach I think would work